# Vue.js 2.x: Mixin cannot be referenced from components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6srsoz85/)

It seems that you can not reference mixin methods (nor the others like computed) from components. If so, how do I define a method that can be shared by the both parent and child? Or, if mixin doesn't work in this way, what's the purpose of mixin after all? I feel I'm missing something fundamental. Example:

```
<div id="parent">
    <child></child>
</div>

<script>
    var mixin, MyVue, vm;
    mixin = {
        methods: {
            say: function () {
                return "Hi";
            }
        }
    }
    MyVue = Vue.extend({
        mixins: [mixin]
    });
    vm = new MyVue({
        el: "#parent",
        components: {
            child: {
                template: "<div>{{ say() }}</div>"
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

and the console says `[Vue warn]: Property or method "say" is not defined...`

Comment: Component parent or child must be instance of MyNew. U should init child as separate component and after that add to vm

Comment: @KirillMatrosov Thanks, but how? I thought I've completed the documentations but it seems I overlooked that part.

Comment: Do you use .vue files?

Comment: @KirillMatrosov No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add global mixin

```
Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        say: function () {
            return "Hi";
        }
    }
})
```

or add mixin to component

```
vm = new MyVue({
    el: "#parent",
    components: {
        child: {
            template: "<div>{{say() }}</div>",
            mixins: [mixin]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ahhhh... okay, it was "Use with caution!" part in the guide. Thank you very much, I was struggling for hours.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use share a mixin between multiple components, but not between all components, you can do that without making it global. Here's how:

in /src/mixins/mixin.js

```
export default {
    created() {
      console.log("created a mixin!")
    },
    methods: {} //any methods you want go here
}
```

in your .vue component (ex: /src/components/Component.vue)

```
<script>
  import Mixin from '../mixins/mixin.js'
  export default {
     mixins: [Mixin],
....
```

The most important thing to note is that I used export default in both my .js file AND my .vue component.